# c++ store special characters ("ç", "á",..etc) on SQLite db

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

My program uses SQLite3 lib to open and execute some querys to a local DB.
This is the function I use to execute a query (with error displaying):

```
void exec(string query, string place_error){
    if( sqlite3_exec(sqldb,query.c_str(),0,0,&db_err) != SQLITE_OK) 
        sql_error(place_error+" - "+(string)db_err);
}
```

Now, if I try to execute something like:

```
exec("INSERT INTO table (testTable) VALUES('ççç')","Insert_Error");
```

It will store symbols like this �.

If I run the sqlite3 shell and execute this exacly same query it won't work as it will store weird characters aswell.

The only way I could store characters like "ç" or "á,é" was using SQLiteStudio, but that's not what I need nor even the sqlite3 shell. I just need this to work on my code.

The DB is defaultly UTF-8 encoded so is there any special statement I should add to the query? Or the problem is just something else.

Thanks

PS: I'm using QT library on my program aswell. All the info's I need to store are normally converted to utf8 (using .toUtf8().constData()). I made sure that the query was right when received on the exec() parameter and all the special characters are right.

Comment: If you are using Qt with aren't you using Qt's Database system?

Comment: Please note that UTF-8 characters are *not* supported when running `sqlite3` in the Windows shell; never use it to input or output non-ASCII data. To check whether your database contains correct data, use any other SQLite tool.

Comment: @CL. SQLiteStudio it's what I use to check my Data and as I said it let's me to insert what I want and how I want. But what I really need is to insert the data with my program

Comment: Like @ahmed said, let Qt handle this for you: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html

Comment: What is the encoding of your source code?

Comment: I'm using sqlite instead of Qt's database here because the DB is used by more than 1 program and I don't use QT in every program. Maybe I'll look for another sqlite library

Comment: @CL. now is UTF-8 without signature

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(MyColumn) FROM MyTable`?

Comment: @CL. just found out something interesting. Using SQLiteSutdio, I see the wrong symbols on my column, but I was testing on other project and if I ask data from the DB it returns me the string with the special characters perfectly fine. So the problem now is to make QT to read them. Your SELECT question would lead me to this conclusion aswell because it is what I did, thanks! Just need to solve the QT issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it appears to be wrong characters when you try to store something like "ç" or "á", those characters are "fine". If I make a function (SELECT) to return the column text to a string, it works. If you're using QT like me you just need to put the return string inside a function

```
QString::fromLatin1(returned_string.c_str());
```

And everything will display fine.